# Parse send notification when object modified

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to send a Push Notification through Parse Cloud Code when a certain object has been modified - "dirty"

I think I am almost there, but received an error because I believe am creating a new user instead of querying for one.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Fact", function(request, response) {
  var dirtyKeys = request.object.dirtyKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < dirtyKeys.length; ++i) {
    var dirtyKey = dirtyKeys[i];
    if (dirtyKey === "isValid") {

      //send push
      // Creates a pointer to _User with object id of userId

      var targetUser = new Parse.User();
      // targetUser.id = userId;
      targetUser.id = request.object.userID;

      var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      query.equalTo('user', targetUser);

      Parse.Push.send({
        where: query,
        data: {
          alert: "Your Fact was approved :)"
        }
      });

      return;
    }
  }
  response.success();
});
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349051/3562138) related to my problem.  My question now is how to integrate the user query in my beforeSave block.  Ideally I would create another function for the user query and place that in my beforeSave block.

**5/14 Update
I took @toddg's advice and fixed the before save.  Here is a clearer picture of what I am trying to do and the new error.

[image: Updating of the entry]
[image: error]

Comment: It's better to put notification code in after save block. In the code above response.success() might run before sending push notification. Also the return; prevents it from notifying response.success() or response.error(). I recommend moving notification stuffs to afterSave

Comment: What's the error you're getting by the way?

Comment: I was getting this error - "Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved ParseObject"

Answer (score 0):

A couple points (as @Subash noted in the comments) before I get into the code:

1. `Parse.Push.send` is an async operation, so you'll want to ensure you call `response.success()` after your push send completes. I'm going to deal with this using Promises, as I think they are more flexible than callbacks. If you're not familiar, read about them [here](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)
2. The return in your if statement will likely prevent the `response.success()` from being called.

Here's my recommended way of doing it:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Fact", function(request, response) {

  // Keep track of whether we need to send the push notification
  var shouldPushBeSent = false;

  var dirtyKeys = request.object.dirtyKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < dirtyKeys.length; ++i) {
    var dirtyKey = dirtyKeys[i];

    if (dirtyKey === "isValid") {
      shouldPushBeSent = true;
    }
  }

  if (shouldPushBeSent) {

      //send push
      // Creates a pointer to _User with object id of userId

      var targetUser = new Parse.User();
      // targetUser.id = userId;
      targetUser.id = request.object.userId;

      var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

      // We want to pass the User object to the query rather than the UserId
      query.equalTo('user', targetUser);
      Parse.Push.send({
        where: query, // Set our Installation query
        data: {
          alert: "Your fact was approved"
        }
      }).then(function(){

        // Now we know the push notification was successfully sent
        response.success();
      }, function(error){

        // There was an error sending the push notification
        response.error("We had an error sending push: " + error);
      });
  } else {
    // We don't need to send the push notification.
    response.success();
  }
});
```

By the way, I'm assuming that you have a column on your Installation class that tracks which user is associated with each Installation.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!  This looks great, going to implement it shortly.  I do have an Installation class, but I don't have a userID column there. Is that what I would need to add?  And then I would have to send that userId from the iOS app to Parse?

Comment: for others who are trying to add a column to installation, very simple.  here is how i did       
        `let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.setObject((user?.objectId!)!, forKey: "userID")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()`